# Skip some special character

Tags: java

I need to skip some of special character. I already have written a piece of code. But it is pure Java code.

```
    String val = menuItemLabelTB.getValue();
    boolean spclCharecterCheck = false;
    String specialCharacters="!#$%&'()*+,.:;=?@[]^`{|}~";

    for (int i = 0; i < val.length(); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < specialCharacters.length(); j++) {
            if(val.charAt(i) == specialCharacters.charAt(j))
                spclCharecterCheck = true;
        }
    }
```

If I want to minimize the complexity by using `regex`, then is it possible to do that?? Or do I need to use any other Java built in function.

Comment: Yes, it's possible using regex, so now is the time for you to **learn regex**, so you will know how to build the regex pattern.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you could do this with a `Pattern` and a *regular expression*. Like,

```
// Note that the literal [](s) have to be escaped below,
String specialCharacters = "[!#$%&'()*+,.:;=?@\\[\\]^`{|}~]";
String val = "a{b}c";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(specialCharacters);
System.out.println(p.matcher(val).replaceAll(""));
```

Which outputs

```
abc
```

Comment: Thanks. Actually I need to compile this Java code inside a GWT Project. So whenever I'm using Pattern Matcher. Then it is showing compilation error.

Comment: [`import java.util.regex.Pattern;`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the characters that you would like to remove in a String and then use a stream to remove the unwanted characters.

```
String specialCharacters="!#$%&'()*+,.:;=?@[]^`{|}~";
String val = "a{b}c";

String result = val
            .chars()
            .mapToObj(a -> String.valueOf((char) a))
            .filter(a -> !specialCharacters.contains(a))
            .reduce((t, u) -> t + u)
            .orElse(" ");

    System.out.println(result);
```

Which prints out

```
abc
```